# How can I add an option in the beginning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have html select,

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

I need to add new option in this select.
If I try like this:

```
$('#myselect').appendTo($('<option>my-option</option>'));
```

the my-option have added to the end

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>my-option</option>
</select>
```

How can I add an option in the beginning (as first)?
Like this:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option>my-option</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you mean [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append), rather than [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo).  `append` adds the content of the parameter to the selection; `appendTo` appends the selection to the element designated in the parameter.

Second, perhaps intuitively, you can use [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend):

```
$('#myselect').prepend($('<option>my-option</option>'));
```

Comment: hehe, a lot of people overlook the actual definition of "append"

Answer (score 16):

In plain old javascript (POJS) you'd use `insertBefore()`, e.g.

```
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
var opt = new Option('', 'my-option');
select.insertBefore(opt, select.firstChild);
```

Comment: I used something very similar. I changed the last line to: select.insertBefore(opt, select.options[0]); The advantage is that this way, you can insert your option anywhere in the select, which is what I needed to do.

Comment: IMO this is the preferred option over jQuery. See also: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzawb.gif

Comment: If someone is confused (as I was), "POJS" is not a framework, but just vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Use `prependTo()`

```
$('#myselect').prependTo($('my-option'));//typo?
```

 
You might have meant this

```
$('#myselect').prepend($('<option>my-option</option>'));
```

http://api.jquery.com/prependTo

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

But your code is actually the other way around. This might be a typo. In any case, the methods available are `prepend()` and `prependTo()`