# add option to select menu at the beginning of the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

How can I add an option to a menu at the begining of the select menu?

I know the append will add the end

```
   SomeSelectMenu.append(NewElement);
```

But how will I add at the beginning? 
Here is an example:

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Please specify an answer with Jquery and one without (if possible)
Thanks

Comment: probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: for adding at the begining use `prepend()` instead of `append`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an option in the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934113/how-can-i-add-an-option-in-the-beginning)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are so close! :)

```
   .prepend( content, [content] )

$('select').prepend('<option value="i-came-first">Hey!</option>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/