# I got geolocation and i need to make that obtained city as an option in select tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code by which I can print the details I obtained by using geolocation :

```
<p>City: <span id="city"></span></p>
```

Thw below code is the select tag.
How can i place the value of "city" in option 1 : --Choose Location--

```
<select class="chosen-select">
<option value="1">- Choose Location -</option>
<option value="2">USA</option>
<option value="3">Ukraine</option>
<option value="4">France</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please share some more code?

Comment: maybe you could see this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an option in the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934113/how-can-i-add-an-option-in-the-beginning)

Comment: function success(position) {
            var GEOCODING = '';
            $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
 $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);             $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name)              $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);               $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
                $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
            })
        }

Comment: Sir I  using id=city i get the city name. How can i make that city as an option?? That is the doubt. I am weak in js

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var select = $('.chosen-select');
select.append('<option value="5">' + location.results[0].address_components[2].lo‌​ng_name + '</option>');
select.val('5');
```

Comment: Sir, I need only city as an option. How to enable that only

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. Why would you even have the other options there if you only want city?

Comment: I obatin all data for other purposes. I really need city to be print as an option??